# Why is my global variable null?

Tags: javascript

```
var matte_canvas_width = $("#matte_canvas").width();
var matte_canvas_height = $("#matte_canvas").height();
function moulding_draw(img, fillet)
{

  //var matte_canvas_width = $("#matte_canvas").width();
  //var matte_canvas_height = $("#matte_canvas").height();
  console.log("matte_canvas_width: " + matte_canvas_width);
  console.log("matte_canvas_height: " + matte_canvas_height);
}
```

When I declare the variables outside of the function, the console outputs null as the values. Why is this happening?

Comment: because in moment when you assign value to variable `$("#matte_canvas").width();` is null, in moment when you trigger function `$("#matte_canvas").width();` is not null

Comment: It's not clear what the outside scope is - perhaps you're not in global scope there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct way of doing this will be

```
var matte_canvas_width;
var matte_canvas_height;

$(document).ready(function() {
    matte_canvas_width = $("#matte_canvas").width();
    matte_canvas_height = $("#matte_canvas").height();
    moulding_draw("", "");
});

function moulding_draw(img, fillet)
{

  //var matte_canvas_width = $("#matte_canvas").width();
  //var matte_canvas_height = $("#matte_canvas").height();
  console.log("matte_canvas_width: " + matte_canvas_width);
  console.log("matte_canvas_height: " + matte_canvas_height);
}
```

Comment: I still get null for those values

Comment: This is giving the output : http://jsfiddle.net/xkMKs/2/

go check the console@AllisonC

Comment: yes,I forgot, you need to call the function as well :) updated answer

Answer (score 2):

the lines

```
var matte_canvas_width = $("#matte_canvas").width();
var matte_canvas_height = $("#matte_canvas").height();
```

should be called at the time when the dom is properly loaded.

Comment: How do I ensure the dom is properly loaded?

Comment: wrap the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){   });`.. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkMKs/3/). or refer @ZaheerAhmed's comment.

Comment: @AllisonC: I really encourage you to read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/): *"To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) [...]"*

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it was never anything in the first place, though you *think* you have set it.

How to you know `$("#matte_canvas").width();` is giving you the value initially?